# Evaluating Indefinite Integral

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

$$∫  \frac{1}{(1-x^3)^{1/3}}\, dx$$

I tried substituting $1-x^3$ as $t^3$ but I am not able to calculate it after that.
Thanks!

Comment: Why should this be an elementary function?

Comment: Are you familiar with the hypergeometric function?

Comment: I'm not actually.

Comment: I don't think there is a "simple" answer to that: Wolfram Alpha gives a fairly complicated expression involving an Appell's hypergeometric function of 2 variables.

Comment: Maple gives the following answer $$x{\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}(1/3,1/3;\,4/3;\,{x}^{3})}$$

Comment: Set $x=z^{1/3}$ and have a look at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html

Comment: See [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) and the [Risch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

For solving

$$
I=∫\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{1-x^3}}\, \mathrm{d}x
$$

Let $t=\dfrac{x}{\sqrt[3]{1-x^3}}$,

solved

$$
\begin{aligned}
x&=\frac{t}{\sqrt[3]{t^3+1}}\\
\mathrm{d}x&=\frac{1}{(t^3+1)\sqrt[3]{t^3+1}}\mathrm{dt}\\
\end{aligned}
$$

and

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{1-x^3}}=\sqrt[3]{t^3+1}
$$

then

$$
I = \int\frac{\sqrt[3]{t^3+1}}{(t^3+1)\sqrt[3]{t^3+1}}\mathrm{dt}=\int\frac{1}{t^3+1}\mathrm{d}t
$$

---

The next part is simple.

$$
\begin{aligned}
I
&= \frac{1}{3}\int\frac{1}{1+(-1)^{2/3} t}+\frac{1}{1-(-1)^{1/3}t}+\frac{1}{t+1}\mathrm{d}t\\
&= \frac{1}{3}\left(\ln (t+1)-(-1)^{1/3} \ln \left((-1)^{1/3}-t\right)+(-1)^{2/3} \ln \left(t+(-1)^{2/3}\right)\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{3} \left(\ln \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt[3]{1-x^3}}+1\right)+(-1)^{2/3} \ln \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt[3]{1-x^3}}+(-1)^{2/3}\right)-(-1)^{1/3} \ln \left((-1)^{1/3}-\frac{x}{\sqrt[3]{1-x^3}}\right)\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Finally, take the derivation and verify that the result is correct.

```
D[1 / 3 (-(-1)^(1 / 3) Log[(-1)^(1 / 3) - x / (1 - x^3)^(1 / 3)] + Log[1 + x / (1 - x^3)^(1 / 3)] + (-1)^(2 / 3) Log[(-1)^(2 / 3) + x / (1 - x^3)^(1 / 3)]), x] // FullSimplify
```